# ExpressiveAnnotations on dynamic form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation, expressiveannotations

I am using ExpressiveAnnotations on a C# MVC project. I have no problem in using it on validating the model inside the view. However I would like to extend the form at run time by adding more input elements via JavaScript. After adding the elements I use these scripts to recreate the validations for the form:

```
var form = $("form").removeData("validator").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
```

The elements are added with `data-val-assertthat`, `data-val-assertthat-fieldsmap`, `data-val-assertthat-expression` and some other `data-val-xxx` attributes. The validation seems to work on the new elements however the error messages are all empty. I think I must has done something wrong here. Any hint?

Comment: If the validation error messages are empty/missing, what makes you say the validation *"seems to work"*?  What about your JavaScript error console?

Comment: Invalid input would trigger an error to be shown in the summary and the corresponding control was highlighted correctly but the error message shown in the summary is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for quite some time on this problem and finally located the problem for my current ASP .NET MVC project. The problem is hidden in how I show the errors. Previously I have codes like the following:

```
$("form").bind("invalid-form.validate", function (form, validator) {
  $(validator.errorList).each(function () {
    $("<li/>").html(this.message).appendTo(msg);
  });
});
```

The problem is `this.message` is empty for those dynamically added elements?! My workaround is:

```
$(validator.errorList).each(function () {
  var error = this.message;
  if (!!!error) {
    error = $(this.element).attr("data-val-" + this.method);
  }
  $("<li/>").html(error).appendTo(msg);
});
```

I have no idea why the error message was empty in my ASP .NET MVC project. I have tried creating a simpe test on JSFiddle but everything is working as expected....